# Youtube iframe is blocking scroll (perfect scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api, perfect-scrollbar

can u help me with one issue. 
i can't scroll page when mouse is over youtube iframe

I don't know what else i can add here.

```js
$('.container').perfectScrollbar();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  background: url('https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/azusa.jpg') top left no-repeat;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 720px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil necessitatibus nemo dolore totam fugiat magni, laudantium nostrum ducimus atque numquam, vitae error, libero voluptas obcaecati. Molestias cum, sed enim cumque sit minus laborum quasi, illum tempore quidem quaerat temporibus corporis itaque qui dolores eius nulla. Officiis deleniti ab laborum cupiditate assumenda enim unde ducimus quam aperiam magni totam quasi similique voluptas aliquid voluptatibus voluptate blanditiis beatae possimus explicabo, nihil, dolor delectus, omnis nisi, quia quod. Tempora, nihil. Optio dolor nulla repellendus inventore reiciendis, animi rem, necessitatibus aut commodi repudiandae illo expedita deserunt aliquam! Iste nam iusto id, dolor perferendis accusantium impe
  
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4qcetGktEuc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
  
  eaque minus nostrum quis optio consequatur quo  nulla, qui dicta. Sunt officia laboriosam adipisci consectetur eius atque nobis dignissimos magnam. Ratione quis modi, minima magni, quos dolorem quasi nemo sunt nisi unde itaque temporibus fugit officia accusamus perferendiperspiciatis, quod eius laboriosam cumque numquam vel est sed illo. Placeat nemo amet id, consequuntur molestias culpa eligendi commodi maxime, sapiente eveniet totam voluptatibus natus harum voluptas perferendis quae tempora nulla, repellat temporibus, ex odit. Expedita dolore, incidunt similique veritatis perspiciatis repudiandae sunt sequi magni inventore mollitia tempore impedit quasi ea dolorem porro, accusamus laboriosam. Aperiam magni commodi laudantium natus. Atque quidem tempora temporibus recus Cupiditate a voluptatum repellat aliquam architecto ipsa non sint laudantium necessitatibus inventore natus ab dolor, illum sit officia enim expedita iste perferendis libero! Corrupti praesentium id expedita rerum, quos optio vitae ipsum! Sequi sit fugiat inventore temporibus consequuntur eum labore officia fugit. Illo sequi distinctio quos illum id architecto quisquam facere perferendis. Voluptate pariatur, molestias voluptates animi voluptatem deserunt, assumenda natus libero ex qui omnis error perspiciatis.
</div>
```

Comment: Did you solved the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @NineCattoRules no :[  .. i have changed this plugin to "angular-nanoscroller": "0.2.1"